# Speed of car with sound

Tags: sound

I've got this task:

> A traffic policeman standing on the highway notices a change in tone of exactly one major third (f2/f1 = 4/5).
>
> What speed can he infer? Speed of sound c = 340 m/s

I've got this attempt: 340 m/s * (1+√5/4) = 765m/S = 2754 km/h

Can someone tell me if this is correct or if I'm completely wrong?

Comment: Ahh -- homework?  Has your book discussed how to derive the Doppler effect from first principles?  Can you start with a car moving at 765m/s emitting a tone, and predict the tone perceived by a listener from those first principles?

Comment: Your proposed solution would require strapping a jet engine to the car. So, sorry, that's wrong.

Comment: Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect

Answer (score 1):

Hints

1. Define the frequency of the car as $f_0$, the heard frequency when it's approaching as $f1$ and the heard frequency when it's departing as $f_2$
2. Write the Doppler formula for both $f_1$ and $f_2$ using a receiver velocity of 0 (since the policeman is stationary with respect to the air) and a car velocity of $v_s$. Pay attention to the sign of the source velocity.
3. Write the ratio of both formulas and equal it to a major third. $f_0$ should drop out and you are left with a single equation for $v_s$
4. Solve for $v_s$